# Setting up InputLayer for 7 Datapoints in Array

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I'm setting up an environment for simulated autonomous driving and I can not figure out how to make an appropriate InputLayer

I extracted Data from the simulation environment (PolyVR https://github.com/Victor-Haefner/polyvr) needed for a navigation on street.
This is packed in an Array of this kind:

```
# nextnnInput: type: float32 
# [0] = Velocity {0, inf}
# [1] = Throttle state {0, 1}
# [2] = steering angle {-1, 1}
# [3] = Distance to Path {-inf, inf}
# [4-6] = Path Dir[x, y, z] at nearest Point on Path
```

I created a simple model according to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential

```
new_input_size = len(nextnnInput)
new_output_size = 3 # represents throttle, break, steering
newModel = tf.keras.Sequential()
newModel.add(layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu', input_shape=(new_input_size,)))
newModel.add(layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu))
newModel.add(layers.Dense(new_output_size, activation='sigmoid'))



newModel.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001),
          loss='mean_squared_error',
          metrics=['accuracy', 'mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'])
```

As a test I tried

```
`newModel.predict( nextnnInput )`
```

as well as

```
`newModel.predict( tf.Variable(nextnnInput, tf.float32), steps=1 )`
```

both resulted in

> Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (7,) but got array with shape (1,)

and when setting input_shape=(1,) it functions, but every data point is interpreted as independent so it returned 7 x 3 output points.

Now how do I setup the Model correctly for my single data point?
(Later this will be a reinforced learning algorithm)

Comment: You should change the shape of nextnnInput to 1X7 or batch_size X7 and new_input_size = nextnnInput.shape[1]

Comment: sry, I do not quite understand: nextnnInput is from type list, therefor as no shape attribute. Can you help me understand what do you mean when saying 'shape of nextnnInput to 1X7' maybe a little code example, Thanks in advance *thumbs up*

Comment: You can change it  next to array with  np.array(nextnnInput )